# Suppose that $f \in \mathcal{C}^{1}([a, b])$. Prove that $|f(x)| \leqslant \frac{1}{2}|f(a)+f(b)|+\int_{a}^{b}\left|f^{\prime}\right|$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, inequality, sobolev-spaces

I've tried to prove it through the following way but failed. There is a gap that I can't get through.

$$
|f(x)| = \left|\int^b_x f'-f(b)\right| = \left| \int^x_a f'+f(a)\right|,
$$
So
$$
2|f(x)|=\left|\int^b_x f'-f(b)\right| + \left|\int^x_a f'+f(a)\right|
$$
Thus
$$
2|f(x)|
 = \left|\int^b_x f'-f(b)\right| + \left|\int^x_a f'+f(a) \right|
 \le \left| \int^b_x f'\right| + |f(b)| + \left|\int^x_a f'\right|+|f(a)|
$$
Since we have
$$
\left| \int^b_x f' \right| \le \int^b_x |f'|
\quad \text{ and } \quad
\left| \int^x_a f' \right| \le \int^x_a |f'|
$$
Thus
$$
\left|\int^b_x f'\right| + \left| \int^x_a f' \right|
 \le \int^b_x |f'| + \int^x_a |f'|
 =   \int^b_a |f'|
$$
But the problem is that I can't have $|f(b)|+|f(a)|\le|f(a)+f(b)|$
So I think I probably went in a wrong way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is the trick you are missing: Since $f$ is continuous, there exists $c$ such that $f(c)=\frac{f(a)+f(b)}2$.

Now $|f(x)|\le |f(c)|+\int_c^x| f’|$ and it’s easy to finish.

Comment: Oh，thank you!!!

Comment: Thank you also from me...for your recent comment.